# Reshape tensor using placeholder value

Tags: tensorflow

I want to reshape a tensor using the [int, -1] notation (to flatten an image, for example). But I don't know the first dimension ahead of time. One use case is train on a large batch, then evaluate on a smaller batch.

Why does this give the following error: `got list containing Tensors of type '_Message'`?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28])
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)

def reshape(_batch_size):
    return tf.reshape(x, [_batch_size, -1])

reshaped = reshape(batch_size)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run([reshaped], feed_dict={x: np.random.rand(100, 28, 28), batch_size: 100})

    # Evaluate
    sess.run([reshaped], feed_dict={x: np.random.rand(8, 28, 28), batch_size: 8})
```

Note: when I have the reshape outside of the function it seems to work, but I have very large models that I use multiple times, so I need to keep them in a function and pass the dim using an argument.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make this work, replace the function:

```
def reshape(_batch_size):
    return tf.reshape(x, [_batch_size, -1])
```

…with the function:

```
def reshape(_batch_size):
    return tf.reshape(x, tf.pack([_batch_size, -1]))
```

The reason for the error is that [`tf.reshape()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape) expects a value that is convertible to a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) as its second argument. TensorFlow will automatically convert a list of Python numbers to a `tf.Tensor` but will not automatically convert a mixed list of numbers and tensors (such as a [`tf.placeholder()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/io_ops.html#placeholder))—instead raising the somewhat unintuitive error message you saw.

The [`tf.pack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#pack) op takes a *list* of objects convertible to a tensor, and converts each element individually, so it can handle the combination of a placeholder and an integer.

Comment: I'm running into some problems using tf.pack() later downstream. `x = reshape(100)` no longer allows me to do `x.get_shape().as_list()[-1]`. It says Nonetype is not iterable, so it is losing shape information. Any comment on this?

Comment: Try specifying `shape=()` when you define your `batch_size` placeholder. You can also use `Tensor.set_shape()` to provide additional shape information that isn't inferred, if you rely on it later on.

Comment: In newer versions, `tf.pack` is replaced with `tf.stack` and I could not use a list containing None with it. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

hi all the issue is due to Keras version. I tried above all without any success. Uninstall Keras and install via pip. It worked for me.

I was facing this error with Keras 1.0.2 & resolved with Keras 1.2.0

Hope this will help. Thank you