# How to add more data during the training of a deep neural network using Keras or Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to write a neural network. But I need to do something to the data during the training. For example, I have 5 convolution layers, after the 3rd layer, I need to change the shape of the output, and add more data to one of its dimension. Then the manipulated data will be fed into the 4th layer.

The problem I have is, the input data dimension is not fixed, it should be got from the data in the training phase. When doing reshape, the Tensorflow will always give errors `the dimension must be specified` because I put `None` for the dimension.

In this case, is there any solution for this problem? Or could we divide the network into two parts, after the first part finished we manipulate the data and then continue to the second part?

Thank you for your time!

**Updates:**
For example, the output of 3rd layer is `[1, 1, L, 5]`, in which `L` is derived from the input and is not a fixed number. If we define `v_1, v_2, ..., v_L` is the vectors of each point in `L` with the features as that in depth `5`, i.e. `shape(v_i)=[1, 5]`.  I want to change it to a new shape `[1, L, L, 12]`, in which `L` is the same one, and in the depth dimension the data is from the concatenation of `v_i` and `v_j` plus `2` more new data.

Comment: Could you provide us more details about how the dimension of data is varying?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko please see the updates for more details.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35374958/reshape-tensor-using-placeholder-value

Answer (score 0):

You can get the runtime value for the shape of the input dimension from `tf.shape`, and then pass this instead of `None` to `tf.reshape`.